# base64 string to image returns only single image in C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I Am getting Images from Reporting service engine in terms of byte array.

```
 byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);//base64 is an byte array
```

I am converting this byte array to to image

```
 MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
 ms1.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
System.Drawing.Image images = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms1, true);**
```

But when I save it it stores only first image

```
 images.Save(Server.MapPath("~/img.png"),System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

it must save two images.I am not able to detect base64 first image or second image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue from this URL [How to show multi paged image in <img/> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560070/how-to-show-multi-paged-image-in-img-tag)

At bottom of page they provide solution working fine....

First- Get all the frames from the stream of image as list of Images

```
public List<Image> GetAllFrames(Stream sm)
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(sm);
    int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
    {
        bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx);
        MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

        images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream));
    }
    return images;
    }
```

Second - Combine all frames in to a single bitmap.

```
public Bitmap CombineAllFrames(List<Image> test)
{
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    Bitmap finalImage = null;
    try
    {
        foreach (Bitmap bitMap in test)
        {
            height += bitMap.Height;
            width = bitMap.Width > width ? bitMap.Width : width;
        }
        finalImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics gc = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
        {
            gc.Clear(Color.White);
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (Bitmap bitmap in test)
            {
                gc.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, offset, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
                offset += bitmap.Width;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return finalImage;
}
```

This methods creates a bitmap which will append all the frames into single one vertically. If you want it horizontally make update it to

```
width += bitmap.Width;
height = bitmap.Height > height ? bitmap.Height : height;
g.DrawImage(image,  new System.Drawing.Rectangle(offset, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
```

Third step - Now if you want a byte array for the created image call the below method

```
public byte[] GetBytesFromImage(Bitmap finalImage)
{
    ImageConverter convertor = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])convertor.ConvertTo(finalImage, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only saving a single image from that byte array. PNGs don't contain multiple images, so you would have to know where to "split" the base64 so you get two images. See the pseudocode below to get an idea of what I am saying:

```
int i = 1;
string split = "//**//";
// the string "//**//" was inserted so we know where to split the string to 
// extract mutiple images. It can be any string value
foreach (var b64str in base64.Split(split))
{
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64str);//base64 is an byte array
    MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms1.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image images = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms1, true);
    images.Save(Server.MapPath("~/img" + i.ToString() + ".png"),System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Derreck Dean but How can I detect second image from base64 image you are correct we can create logic but what is the way to detect second image start from this base64 string

Comment: If you combined the byte arrays of the two images, it may not be possible to just "detect" where the first image stops and the second image begins without some sort of token you could use to split by. Although, I suppose most PNGs start with a header, but how do you know for sure that header doesn't exist farther down in the file?

Comment: You are right , By the way by online decoder tool i am able to generate two images  but not by C# I also tried with .jpg format it worked online like below tool http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter but not by c# it always show me first image

Comment: All came from Report service

Comment: Yeah what's most likely happening is that the PNG or JPEG has an end-of-file marker built in and the image viewer adheres to that, showing the first image, and ignoring the rest of the file. http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html - PNG files always start with the bytes `137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10` so you could look for those. A dirty shortcut would be to split the byte array by those bytes and prepend each one with the bytes (restoring them), provided all the files are PNG files.